# Can I reversing these buttons easier on myself?

Tags: javascript, html, css

So, I'm wondering if i can make this any simpler (less repetition in the javascript) and whether or not I can make it so the title only turns black when hitting a button if it is that buttons color. If the second part of the question is possible it doesn't need to be simpler I'm just trying to figure out how to make the function target only tags with a specific attribute (style). Is this possible?

I'm new to coding I've been trying to figure this out for a few hours and can't find something already uploaded... possibly due to my lack of being able to condense the question.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>
        Flood
    </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Style.css">
    <style>
        h1 {
            text-align: center;
            padding-left: 30%;
            padding-right: 30%;
            width: 40%;
        }

        p {
            font-size: 14pt
        }

    </style>
</head>
<body>
<section class="mainpage">
    <h1 id="FS"> Fun Stuff </h1>
    <div>
        <button id="Red"> Red</button>
        <button id="Blue"> Blue</button>
        <button id="Yellow"> Yellow</button>
        <button id="Blink"> Blink</button>
    </div>
    <div id="explaination">
        <p>Click the buttons at the top to see what I mean.
        </p>
    </div>
</section>
<script>
    const a = document.getElementById("FS");
    const b = document.getElementById("Red");
    const c = document.getElementById("Blue");
    const d = document.getElementById("Yellow");
    const e = document.getElementById("Blink");

    /*reset Functions*/

    function blackFunctionB() {
        a.style.color = "black";
        b.removeEventListener("click", blackFunctionB,);
        b.addEventListener("click", redFunction,);
    }

    function blackFunctionC() {
        a.style.color = "black";
        c.removeEventListener("click", blackFunctionC,);
        c.addEventListener("click", blueFunction,);
    }

    function blackFunctionD() {
        a.style.color = "black";
        d.removeEventListener("click", blackFunctionD,);
        d.addEventListener("click", yellowFunction,);
    }

    function showFunction() {
        a.style.display = "block";
        e.removeEventListener("click", showFunction,);
        e.addEventListener("click", blinkFunction,)
    }

    /*end reset functions*/

    b.addEventListener("click", redFunction,);

    function redFunction() {
        a.style.color = "Red";
        b.removeEventListener("click", redFunction,);
        b.addEventListener("click", blackFunctionB,);
    }

    c.addEventListener("click", blueFunction,);

    function blueFunction() {
        a.style.color = "Blue";
        c.removeEventListener("click", blueFunction,);
        c.addEventListener("click", blackFunctionC,);
    }

    d.addEventListener("click", yellowFunction,);

    function yellowFunction() {
        a.style.color = "Yellow";
        d.removeEventListener("click", yellowFunction,);
        d.addEventListener("click", blackFunctionD,);
    }

    e.addEventListener("click", blinkFunction,);

    function blinkFunction() {
        a.style.display = "none"
        e.removeEventListener("click", blinkFunction,);
        e.addEventListener("click", showFunction,);
    }
</script>
</body>
```

So basically when you click on the yellow button it makes the block turn yellow, then if you hit the blue button it makes it blue, but if you hit the yellow button again it makes it black. Alternatively, when you hit the yellow then blue twice then yellow again it stays black. Is there a way to make it only turn black if you hit the yellow button when it is already yellow?

Comment: Your requirement is not clear. Can you prepare a simple list of expected behavior?

Answer (score 1):

You could make one function that is more generic and can handle all the cases you have:

```js
function toggleCss(elem, attrib, value) {
    elem.style[attrib] = elem.style[attrib] === value ? "" : value;
}

const fs = document.getElementById("FS");

for (let color of ["red", "blue", "yellow"]) {
    const button = document.getElementById(color);
    button.addEventListener("click", () => toggleCss(fs, "color", color));
}
const button = document.getElementById("blink");
button.addEventListener("click", () => toggleCss(fs, "visibility", "hidden"));
```

```html
<section class="mainpage">
    <h1 id="FS"> Fun Stuff </h1>
    <div>
        <button id="red"> Red </button>
        <button id="blue"> Blue </button>
        <button id="yellow"> Yellow </button>
        <button id="blink"> Blink </button>
    </div>
    <div id="explanation">
        <p>Click the buttons at the top to see what I mean.</p>
    </div>
</section>
```

You could even make it more generic by defining data attributes on the buttons which indicate which CSS property needs to toggle:

```js
function toggleCss(elem, attrib, value) {
    elem.style[attrib] = elem.style[attrib] === value ? "" : value;
}

const fs = document.getElementById("FS");

for (const button of document.querySelectorAll("button[data-attr]")) {
    button.addEventListener("click", () =>
        toggleCss(fs, button.dataset.attr, button.dataset.value)
    );
}
```

```html
<section class="mainpage">
    <h1 id="FS"> Fun Stuff </h1>
    <div>
        <button data-attr="color" data-value="red">Red</button>
        <button data-attr="color" data-value="blue">Blue</button>
        <button data-attr="color" data-value="yellow">Yellow</button>
        <button data-attr="visibility" data-value="hidden">Blink</button>
    </div>
    <div id="explanation">
        <p>Click the buttons at the top to see what I mean.</p>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: super intelligent :)

Answer (score 0):

You are over complicating things. Simply check and toggle the black and 2nd color.
You don't have to register/de-register events again and again.

```html
function yellowFunction() {
    var clr = a.style.color;
    if(clr.toLowerCase() === 'yellow')
    a.style.color = "black";
else
    a.style.color = "Yellow";
}
```